# error on 'make' while building opencv from source

Tags: opencv

I'm following this tut: https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html  with a few params I had to set on cmake due to the errors I had been getting...

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -DWITH_VTK=ON ~/fuck/opencv ..
```

This is the error while running 'make':

```
[ 46%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_viz
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_get_version@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_get_id_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `BIO_int_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_NAME_get_entry@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_length@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_set_ex_data@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_set_flags@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `BIO_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSLv23_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ENGINE_load_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_cert_store@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFGetFieldDefaulted@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_check_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ENGINE_by_id@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `BIO_clear_flags@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_write@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_set_verify@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CIPHER_get_bits@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `sk_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFSetWarningHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ENGINE_finish@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `_TIFFmalloc@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_get_ext_d2i@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_get_current_compression@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ENGINE_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_data@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_config@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_load_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFDefaultStripSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CIPHER_get_name@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `sk_num@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFReadTile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_read@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `_TIFFfree@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `BIO_set_flags@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_get_locking_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `sk_value@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFClientOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFNumberOfDirectories@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ERR_put_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ERR_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `BIO_s_socket@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_get_current_cipher@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAImage@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ERR_clear_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ENGINE_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_set_bio@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ERR_reason_error_string@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_connect@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_pending@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFSetDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFReadScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.10: undefined reference to `TIFFNumberOfTiles@LIBTIFF_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/viz/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_viz.dir/build.make:239: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_test_viz' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_viz] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4014: recipe for target 'modules/viz/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_viz.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/viz/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_viz.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

System information :

```
__Hardware Information__
Machine               : x86_64
CPU Name              : skylake
CPU Features          : 
adx aes avx avx2 bmi bmi2 clflushopt cmov cx16 f16c fma fsgsbase lzcnt mmx movbe
pclmul popcnt prfchw rdrnd rdseed sgx sse sse2 sse3 sse4.1 sse4.2 ssse3 xsave
xsavec xsaveopt xsaves

__OS Information__
Platform              : Linux-4.13.0-32-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
Release               : 4.13.0-32-generic
System Name           : Linux
Version               : #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018
OS specific info      : debianstretch/sid
glibc info            : glibc 2.9

__Python Information__
Python Compiler       : GCC 7.2.0
Python Implementation : CPython
Python Version        : 3.6.3
Python Locale         : en_IN ISO8859-1

__LLVM information__
LLVM version          : 5.0.0

__CUDA Information__
Found 1 CUDA devices
id 0        b'GeForce 940MX'                              [SUPPORTED]
                      compute capability: 5.0
                           pci device id: 0
                              pci bus id: 1
Summary:
    1/1 devices are supported
CUDA driver version   : 9010
CUDA libraries:
Finding cublas
    named  libcublas.so.8.0.88
    trying to open library...   ok
Finding cusparse
    named  libcusparse.so.8.0.61
    trying to open library...   ok
Finding cufft
    named  libcufft.so.8.0.61
    trying to open library...   ok
Finding curand
    named  libcurand.so.8.0.61
    trying to open library...   ok
Finding nvvm
    named  libnvvm.so.3.1.0
    trying to open library...   ok
    finding libdevice for compute_20... ok
    finding libdevice for compute_30... ok
    finding libdevice for compute_35... ok
    finding libdevice for compute_50... ok

__Conda Information__
conda_build_version   : 3.0.27
conda_env_version     : 4.4.9
platform              : linux-64
python_version        : 3.6.3.final.0
root_writable         : True
```

CUDA 9.1 
OpenCV was working fine until I installed CUDA toolkit on my system.

Comment: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I installed CUDA 8.0 alongside and ran a different script for OpenCV : https://github.com/ap193uee/Install-Scripts/blob/master/opencv3.sh

Solved my problem.